# Hide multiple divs until individual links are mouseover then show each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML code...

```
<div class="circles">
<ul>
    <li><a id="links" href="#" class="first links">Supply
Chain</a></li>
    <li><a id="links" href="#" class="links">Quality
Control</a></li>
    <li><a id="links" href="#" class="links">Manufacturing
</a></li>
    <li><a id="links" href="#" class="links">Material
Handling</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="supply" class="circletext">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">OUR CAPABILITIES</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem nunc. <a>
Click here to read more about our capabilities</a> or select a service below.</p>

</div>
<div id="quality" class="circletext">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Quality Control</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem nunc. <a>
Click here to read more about our capabilities</a> or select a service below.</p>


</div>
<div id="manufacturing" class="circletext">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Manufacturing</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem nunc. <a>
Click here to read more about our capabilities</a> or select a service below.</p>

</div>
<div id="material" class="circletext">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Material Handling</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem nunc. <a>
Click here to read more about our capabilities</a> or select a service below.</p>

</div>
```

I need to have the divs that have the class .circletext to be hidden to start.  Then I need anytime one of the links #links to be hovered that its corresponding div shows. So if the first Supply Chain link is hovered then the div id #supply shows up.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.circletext').hide();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#links').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('.circletext').show();
        },
    function() {
        jQuery('.circletext').hide();
        });
});
</script>
```

I know I need to add some specific ids or classes.  Just some help would be great (and if they could have some fade in fade out effect too).

Comment: ID's must be unique for a document. You use the same `id='links'` for all, so `$('#links')` find only the first. Make ID's unique (links1, links2, ...) and use the class-selector instead: `$('.links')` to select all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code ........

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.circletext1').hide();
 jQuery('.circletext2').hide();
 jQuery('.circletext3').hide();
 jQuery('.circletext4').hide();
    jQuery('#links1').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.circletext1').show();
        jQuery('.circletext2').hide();
     jQuery('.circletext3').hide();
     jQuery('.circletext4').hide();
    });
 jQuery('#links2').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.circletext2').show();
        jQuery('.circletext1').hide();
     jQuery('.circletext3').hide();
     jQuery('.circletext4').hide();
    });
 jQuery('#links3').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.circletext3').show();
        jQuery('.circletext1').hide();
     jQuery('.circletext2').hide();
     jQuery('.circletext4').hide();
    });
 jQuery('#links4').hover(function() {
        jQuery('.circletext4').show();
        jQuery('.circletext1').hide();
     jQuery('.circletext2').hide();
     jQuery('.circletext3').hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circles">
<ul>
    <li><a id="links1" href="#" class="first links">Supply
Chain</a></li>
    <li><a id="links2" href="#" class="links">Quality
Control</a></li>
    <li><a id="links3" href="#" class="links">Manufacturing
</a></li>
    <li><a id="links4" href="#" class="links">Material
Handling</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="supply" class="circletext1">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">OUR CAPABILITIES</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem nunc. <a>
Click here to read more about our capabilities</a> or select a service below.</p>

</div>
<div id="quality" class="circletext2">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Quality Control</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem nunc. <a>
Click here to read more about our capabilities</a> or select a service below.</p>

</div>
<div id="manufacturing" class="circletext3">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Manufacturing</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem nunc. <a>
Click here to read more about our capabilities</a> or select a service below.</p>

</div>
<div id="material" class="circletext4">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">Material Handling</h2>
<p style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conset adipiscing elit. Mauris et sem nunc. <a>
Click here to read more about our capabilities</a> or select a service below.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: This code worked for me, why not use it Max?  Any better suggestions?

Comment: I have to admit it might work, but its very bad style of coding... you could do it nicer .. for example you are doing multiplying classes and hide every class and will also have to change the css to have handle your new classes... you could for example target the div#supply.circletext instead of renaming it to a new class - do you see what i meen?

Comment: I forgot to mention I also need the div circle text to be able to stay opened if the mouse if hovered over it because there will be "Learn More" buttons at the bottom of the cicletext divs...

Answer (score 0):

inside your doc ready handler put this:

```
$(document).on('hover', '#links', function(){ //or mouseover?
  //do something
  $('#supply').show();
});
```

EDIT:

not sure if the on.'hover' fires...

you could alternatively try:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '#links', function () {
    $("#supply").show();
}).on('mouseleave', '#links', function () {
    $("#supply").hide();
});
```

Comment: set a breakpoint in there and see if the handler actually gets called?

Comment: > Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. Do not confuse the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.

Comment: Vohuman is right, i also researched this! I wont delete it in my comment so people can notice this activly. go with mouseover then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check The JSFiddle :- [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/v1a85og6/1/)

```
 jQuery('.circletext').hide();

 $( ".links" ).hover( function() {
   if(this.id == 'links1'){
      $("#quality").hide();
      $("#manufacturing").hide();
      $("#material").hide();
      $("#supply").show();
   }
   if(this.id == 'links2'){
       $("#supply").hide();
       $("#manufacturing").hide();
       $("#material").hide();
       $("#quality").show();
   }
   if(this.id == 'links3'){
      $("#supply").hide();
      $("#material").hide();
      $("#quality").hide();
      $("#manufacturing").show();
   }
   if(this.id == 'links4'){
     $("#supply").hide();
     $("#manufacturing").hide();
     $("#quality").hide();
     $("#material").show();
   }
});
```

Comment: This doesnt work after I use it in my code.. It has something to do with you using just plain li.. Can we be specific for and ID or Class?

Comment: If this helped you tick it as answer and +1.